# Referencing relative (parent) path with sudomain

Tags: asp.net, subdomain

I have a website with several subdomains that direct the user into a subfolder on my site.  Inside each subfolder is a Default.aspx file which does some processing and then redirects the user to "../Default.aspx".

This works fine if you type the full URL to that page.  If you try to access it through the subdomain, the ".." parent is not being parsed correctly, and just concatenates the subfolder path into the main path and I get a page not found.

The root path of my application is www.domain.com/root.
The subdomain points to subdomain.domain.com/root/subfolder
When I navigate to subdomain.domain.com, I get this error:

"404 - /root/subfolder/root/Default.aspx not found"

All I want is for subdomain.domain.com to redirect the user up one folder level to www.domain.com/root/Default.aspx

Can anyone help?  Is this a feature/restriction of using a shared hosting provider - the subdomains are restricted to the folder where they are pointed?

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a bit confusing, since you mix local paths and URLs together. Am I right that you are trying to do: Page at `subdomain.domain.com/root/subfolder/Default.aspx` redirects to `www.domain.com/root/Default.aspx`?

That means you want to do 2 things:

1. Redirect from sub-domain `subdomain` to sub-domain `www`, and
2. Navigate to a file one folder up.

Both things you can do in a single HTTP redirect. For this, use the `Response.Redirect` method, and make sure that in the URL you use the www sub-domain, and the correct absolute path to the page you want to show.

```cs
Response.Redirect("http://www.domain.com/root/Default.aspx");
```

**Update**

Or, redirect to a URL relative to the current page, in the same domain.

```
Response.Redirect( Page.ResolveClientUrl( "../Default.aspx" ) );
```

**Update 2**

Or, use the Host HTTP header to distinguish on subdomains and switch programatically in your  shared codebase.

Comment: You are mostly correct, and I apologize it was confusing. I rewrote my question several times, trying to simplify each time.  What you said is what I've done as sort of a workaround - it definitely works, but I have 2 issues with it:

1. I lose the subdomain prefix from the URL.  (Not a functional problem, but I wanted the users to still see their subdomain)
2. I have 3 tiers - PRD, TST, and DEV, and with this solution, I need to have conditional redirects based on the tier.

Are subdomain pointers on GoDaddy prevented from redirecting to a page at the parent level or above?  (Security issue?)

Comment: Could you explain why you want to serve a page first from a subfolder and then move up one folder? (in the same subdomain)

Comment: Sure.  I have a core set of pages and code (in the main folder) and when we sign up a new partner, we create a unique URL for them (the subdomain) which redirects into a subfolder specific to that partner so I can do some variable setup to display a unique skin for them.  While each partner has a unique skin, their website functions with the same code behind infrastructure.  Since they got to the site using subdomain.domain.com, I would prefer for the URL to retain their subdomain.

Comment: After the variable setup, I want to redirect them one folder up to display Default.aspx.

Comment: Since you use the same codebase installation for all sites, would it be an alternative option to build-in switching code based on the host HTTP header, instead of working with different paths?

Comment: So are you suggesting that I forward all of the subdomains to the same folder, and then set my variables and such based on the HTTP header?  That probably would work and would eliminate all these headaches.

Comment: FYI, the Page.ResolveClientUrl did not work.  I got the same error message with the concatenation of the paths.  I'm going to try the http headers - that should work.

Comment: That's strange. Have you tried to see what happens with app relative URLs? "~/folder/Default.aspx"

Comment: Your http header solution worked!  This is exactly what I needed.  I have pointed all the subdomains to the same folder (the main code base) and then set my partner-specific variables based on the header. No more trouble with relative paths. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to point all the subdomains to the same folder (the main code base) and then in the Master file, switch based on the http header.  If they are coming in from partner1.domain.com, use css1 - if they are from partner2.domain.com, use css2, etc.

This allows me to use relative paths throughout the code AND preserve the subdomain in the browser's URL bar.

One caveat - if you are testing in multiple environments (I have a DEV and a TST) you need some code to detect which environment you are in and operate a little differently, since the http header host would show something like "localhost:51510".  For me, those subdomains only exist in my Production environment.

Credit to bgever - thanks!